# Auto transfer of luggage between 2 airlines till final destination

Tags: luggage, layovers, dxb, emirates

I have bought a tickets from Harare to Dubai of Rwand Air from their office.  Then I bought a ticket from Dubai to London of Emirates Air.  Both the tickets were separately from their respective offices.
What should I do to ensure that my luggage reaches directly to destination, instead of me having to collect at Dubai Airport and check-in again.

Comment: Most likely you will have to collect your bags and do a full check in in Dubai. Please note that you may also need a valid VISA for Dubai.

Answer (score 7):

After a bit of internet searching it appears that Rwandair and Emirates do not interline baggage with each other. Even if they did, they may not do so on tickets purchased separately like yours. In that case there is no way to avoid collecting your bags at Dubai and rechecking them, aside from traveling with only cabin baggage that fits in the overhead bin and a personal item that fits under the seat.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, this also requires passing through immigration and thus being able to enter UAE.

Answer (score 1):

Two separated itineraries mean that you will *have to* re-check your luggage. That means entering Dubai through passport control, pick up the luggage, go to check-in counter of Emirates and drop it off there while receiving your boarding pass to London. You will need to verify that you have the necessary documents to enter Dubai.

If you do not have the proper documentation to enter Dubai or your layover is extremely short that will not allow you to re-check your bags (entering the country, rechecking the bag, and re-entering security takes quite some time), change your tickets now. Don't get stuck in the situation when you arrive at the airport. Rwandair will probably not allow you to board the plane if you don't have the necessary documents to enter Dubai.

If you are able to re-check the bags but are just asking because "it's too much work", I would suggest just put up with it and re-check the bags. I do it all the time and it's not a lot of trouble.